# Activity as dialog using HoloEverywhere cuts off layout

Tags: android, android-activity, android-holo-everywhere

I'm using the HoloEverywhere library in my Android app to ensure a consistent theme across all supported devices. However, I'm running into trouble with activities that utilize Holo.Theme.Dialog: on my Android 2.2 emulator it displays correctly, but on my Android 4 device (which has the actual Holo theme available) the layout cuts off items on the right edge of the dialog.

My question is, **how can I force devices that have the stock Holo theme to use that instead of HoleEverywhere**? Or, **how can I modify HoloEverywhere to make activities styled as dialogs display correctly on Android 4+ devices**?

Screenshots:

[Dialog in Android 4+](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B21y6wBV8hPGRjF3NW0zX0pkaW8/edit?usp=sharing)

[Dialog in Android 2.2](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B21y6wBV8hPGdmF5N2VkUkhldlU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: How do you style the dialog or how to you create it?

Comment: The dialog is just an activity with the Holo.Theme.Dialog theme applied to it in my manifest. This worked fine before I added HoloEverywhere.

Comment: so, did you fix the problem, how?

Comment: @deadfish I never "solved" it, but I was able to work around it by reworking my activity dialogs into actual Alert Dialogs. Still seems like a bug in HoloEverywhere to me, despite being closed as a non-issue by the developer.

Comment: now it is #484 on github and stack question by myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this bug has been fixed in HoloEverywhere or not, but my solution was to change all of my dialog activity classes to AlertDialogs. This required some code changes, but now I can be sure my dialogs will look and act as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do:

1. In your values folder, create a style in styles.xml file referencing Holo.Theme as a parent. In my case, I used AppBaseTheme

   ```
   <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Holo.Theme.Light"></style>
   ```
2. In your manifest, make sure that you are referencing this style in your activities and in your application tag.

   ```
   <application
     ...
     android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
   ```
3. Create a folder in your res folder named values-11 (if there isn't one already)
4. Create another styles.xml file.
5. Copy the same style you placed earlier in values folder, but reference the built in Holo theme included in 4.0

   ```
   <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"></style>
   ```

Comment: i'm sorry but i dont see here any solution

Comment: Simply put, the app uses AppBaseTheme as the theme, but AppBaseTheme's parent changes depending on the OS version the app is run on. Stuff in the values-11 res folder will be used when the OS version is 11 and up. In values-11, AppBaseTheme's parent is android:Theme.Holo.Light. If the app is not run on OS Version 11 and up, the stuff in values res folder is used instead. In values, AppBaseTheme's parent is Holo.Theme.Light.