# How to change color in settings of Androidapp title?

Tags: android

I wonder how I can change this color (atm blue "Set Phonenumber from partner") to orange like below at the input field:
color: #FF9900

[image]

Does anyone know how to do that?

**Edit:**

I defined my style like this:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/DialogWindowTitle</item>
</style>
```

Here is the DialogWindowTitle style:

```
<style name="DialogWindowTitle_Holo">
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.DialogWindowTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogWindowTitle" parent="@style/DialogWindowTitle_Holo">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.DialogWindowTitle</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.DialogWindowTitle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Holo.DialogWindowTitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```

I have the following activity:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }
}
```

And this is my settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/sectionTwoTitle" >
        <EditTextPreference
            android:title="@string/setPhoneNumber"
            android:summary="@string/setPhoneNumberSum"
            android:key="phoneNumber"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

But this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

this is a good tutorial for you (about styling dialogs)
http://blog.supenta.com/2014/07/02/how-to-style-alertdialogs-like-a-pro/

**OR**   (Last Edit)
you can use a custom dialog :
1-create the dialog layout :

customDialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/app"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/app"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/app"
    android:background="#00ff0700">


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner_2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="@string/details"
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:autoText="false"
                android:textColor="#0061C2" />

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/nom"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:id="@+id/nom"
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/prenom"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:id="@+id/prenom"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/specialite"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:id="@+id/specialite"
                    android:layout_row="4"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/numero"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:id="@+id/num_tel"
                    android:layout_row="3"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/adresse"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:id="@+id/adresse"
                    android:layout_row="5"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/specialite"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/dispo"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:id="@+id/tvDispo"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/heures"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:id="@+id/tvHeures"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/listRdvDispo"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:id="@+id/tvJours"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/OK"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/OK"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_back_2"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Appeler"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_back_2"
                    android:id="@+id/App"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/surCarte"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_back_2"
                    android:id="@+id/Car"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

after that go to your activity and add this:

```
public void afficherDialogue(){
    dialog3 = new Dialog(MainActivity.context);
    dialog3.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog3.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    Cursor medecin = MainActivity.db.lireMedecin(); 
        ((TextView) dialog3.findViewById(R.id.num_tel)).setText("phone number");
            ((TextView) dialog3.findViewById(R.id.nom)).setText("name");
            ((TextView) dialog3.findViewById(R.id.prenom)).setText("last name");
            ((TextView) dialog3.findViewById(R.id.adresse)).setText("addresse");
    Button ok = (Button) dialog3.findViewById(R.id.OK);
    Button App = (Button) dialog3.findViewById(R.id.App);
    Button Car = (Button) dialog3.findViewById(R.id.Car);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog3.dismiss();

        }
    });
    App.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //do something
            dialog3.dismiss();
        }
    });

    Car.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          //do something
            dialog3.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog3.show();

}
```

this is how my dialog looks [image: dialog screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, if I try this, it says that I need API 13 to use "android:TextAppearance.Holo.DialogWindowTitle". Is there any possible way to do it with API 11?

Comment: i will update my post if i find anything about api 11

Comment: does this help ? -> "android:TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.DialogWindowTitle"

Comment: no, this requires API level 14. But I also set my minSDK=13 But the title still stays blue.

Comment: i got something may helps...see the pictures posted here...its caled holoEveryWhere ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623965/activity-as-dialog-using-holoeverywhere-cuts-off-layout

Comment: i have something that i call custom dialog .. its an xml layout ... you can insert a text view as title .. and do every thing like normal layout.. and show it .. if you're intrested i post it as answer. what do you think

Comment: Problem is, that the dialogs from my preference.xml are generated with "addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);"

Comment: i didn't anderstand ..see the answer and tell me what you think.. note with that answer you can customize everything in your dialog

Answer (score 0):

Just call `setTitleColor(int textColor)`; Brief and Exact.

Comment: where do i set t hat?

Comment: Anywhere and anytime, actually, of course, on the UI thread. But for you, `onCreate` or `onResume` is recommended.